# Confirmation emails for testing

Tags: parsing

I am investigating Amadeus for an itinerary management app. I have parsed a few of my own past flight confirmation emails with mixed success, but I'd like a larger sample without having to book airfare on a bunch of airlines.  Does anybody have or know where to find some samples for testing purposes?

I have tried it on a few of my own past confirmations, with partial success.  It may just be that they're out of date.